# Angular 2 Component custom attribute is null in constructor

Tags: javascript, angular

I create a component and I'm trying to send a custom attribute on it. But in the constructor I just get a null. I know that it has something becouse I'm printing the variable.

this is the html where I instantiate the countdown component, that I call from other component:

```
this is how I know voteDate has something{{voteDate}}

<countdown [attr.inputDate]="voteDate"></countdown>
```

and this is the component (I get a null in the constructor):

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'countdown',
    template: `
  <div class="font-poll-countdown">
    Poll Will Close in: {{message}}
  </div>
`
})
export class CountDown implements OnInit {

    private future: Date;
    private futureString: string;
    private diff: Date;

    constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
        this.futureString = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('inputDate');
    }

    dhms(t) {
        var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
        days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
        t -= days * 86400;
        hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24;
        t -= hours * 3600;
        minutes = Math.floor(t / 60) % 60;
        t -= minutes * 60;
        seconds = t % 60;

        return [
            days + 'd',
            hours + 'h',
            minutes + 'm',
            seconds + 's'
        ].join(' ');
    }



    ngOnInit() {
        this.future = new Date(this.futureString);
        Observable.interval(1000).map((x) => {
            this.diff = Math.floor((this.future.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
        }).subscribe((x) => {
            this.message = this.dhms(this.diff);
        });
    }
}
```

I try everything but I'm still getting null  in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `InputMetadata`, where you can pass data through properties. Angular automatically updates data-bound properties during change detection and will pass the same to `countdown` component.

wrap `inputDate` with `[]`(to pass it as property) & then to get access to that value you need to define it inside a component as an `@Input`

```
<countdown [inputDate]="voteDate"></countdown>

//inside your component
@Input() inputDate: Date;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your custom attribute won't be available in the constructor.  You need to wait until the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook is called:

```
ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('inputDate'))
}
```

That said, I like @Pankaj's answer -- use property binding instead.  Then you can pass your date in as an actual JavaScript Date object, if you so desire.  With attributes, you always get a string value.